# Outlook 2021 PST file is corrupt

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, backup, microsoft-office

In Outlook 2021, I have a PST file that has been corrupt and I can't open it. I tried a backup that I made the night before, but this had the same result. I then fished out another backup that I'd made in February--well before the file was corrupted and I got this error message--which worked. But I lost a few months of emails.

SCANPST.EXE didn't help anything with my backup from yesterday. Nor did any Google search. This PST file has all my archived business emails, so I'm pretty screwed if I can't recover it. Is there any way to recover this thing at all?

If it matters, the size of the PST file is a smidge under 1.2 GB. I only started getting this error this morning.

Comment: Make a copy of the PST file, restart, try again with SCANPST.  If that does not work, use Stellar PST repair tools.   https://www.stellarinfo.com/

Comment: Thanks, @John. I got it. At least I can see the file, but unfortunately I need to pay to save anything with it. I don't want to spend $99 to rescue one file. Is there a free tool?

Comment: I have not seen a free tool other than SCANPST.  So if you do not want to pay for Stellar, kiss your PST file goodbye. I have an old license for Stellar because I had to purchase it some years back to repair my file.

Answer (score 0):

What's the PST file? Is it datafile?

If so, it's suggested that you could export it again as a new PST file.

And i notice that you have tried SCANPST.EXE, did you repair the PST file as this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253#:%7E:text=Repair%20an%20Outlook%20data%20file%C2%A0(.pst)%20file) mentioned?

And please note:
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.